# Xcode 6.1 difference in sizes between iPad Air and iPad Retina

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm working on iPad app. iPad simulator has iPad 2, iPad Air and iPad Retina. I finished working on iPad 2 sizes. However, what's the difference in points height between iPad Air and iPad Retina? What's the height in points of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both have 1024 x 768 points. The difference is in the pixel resolution. See http://www.iosres.com/ for a handy reference.

Comment: iPhone 6 screen size height is 667 and iPhone 6 plus screen size height is 736 and iPad Air and Retina screen size height is 768?